# Сравнить URL и удалить href из ссылки (javascript)

Tags: javascript, url

Есть такой код:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){

    var ourURL = window.location.href;
    var docURL = a.href;

    if (ourURL == docURL) {
        ssil.removeAttribute(href);
    }
}
</script>

<a href="ссылка" id=ssil>Ссылка тут</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Надо, чтобы, если URL текущей страницы и значение `href` были идентичны, из ссылки удалялся `href`.

Как заставить его работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var ourURL = window.location.href;
console.log('ourURL - '+ourURL);
var docURL = ssil.href;
console.log('docURL - '+docURL);
if (ourURL == docURL) {
  ssil.removeAttribute('href');
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js" id="ssil">Ссылка тут</a>
```